# If I create a Game Center account, will I lose my Clash of Clans village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I don't have a Game Center account and I play clash of clans. If I create an account, will I lose my village?

Answer (score 1):

You won't lose your clash of clans progress by making a Game Center account.